# wordpress how to create custom taxonmy listing page?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have created this taxonmy  **"builder_name"**

And I am using wp estate theme.

My url is like **mydomain.com/builder_name/natasha-developers/** and its gives the page not found.

```
// add custom taxonomy
register_taxonomy('builder_name', 'estate_property', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'              => __( 'Builder Name','wpestate'),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Builder Name','wpestate'),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Builder Name','wpestate')
    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
     )
);
```

Comment: update Permalink Settings in admin panel


reference link : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-template-not-showing

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: yes, Problem solved. using above solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update Permalink Settings in admin panel reference link : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-template-not-showing